# Detect backspace and del on "input" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to do that?

I tried:

```
var key = event.which || event.keyCode || event.charCode;

if(key == 8) alert('backspace');
```

but it doesn't work...

If I do the same on the keypress event it works, but I don't want to use keypress because it outputs the typed character in my input field. I need to be able to control that

---

my code:

```
  $('#content').bind('input', function(event){

    var text = $(this).val(),
        key = event.which || event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if(key == 8){
      // here I want to ignore backspace and del
    }

    // here I'm doing my stuff
    var new_text = 'bla bla'+text;
    $(this).val(new_text);
  });
```

no character should be appended in my input, besides what I'm adding with val()
actually the input from the user should be completely ignored, only the key pressing action is important to me

Comment: You actually don't need to do the or'ing - event.which is just fine, jQuery normalizes the event object for you. See http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: You're supposed to put the name of the event as the first argument of `.bind`, not a selector. Should be `$('content').bind('keypress', ...`

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Use `.onkeydown` and cancel the removing with `return false;`. Like this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('myInput');

input.onkeydown = function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if( key == 8 || key == 46 )
        return false;
};
```

---

Or with jQuery, because you added a jQuery tag to your question:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var input = $('#myInput');
  input.on('keydown', function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if( key == 8 || key == 46 )
        return false;
  });
});
```

​

Comment: What if you wanted to catch input from a right-click > paste?

Comment: ``keydown`` not works in Chrome Android, it returns emptyness when clicking backspace or del

Comment: In function we have to keep event as parameter then only it will work 
like function(event) --------------------------
var input = document.getElementById('myInput');
input.onkeydown = function(event) {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    if( key == 8 || key == 46 )
        return false;
};

Comment: with jQuery it internally filters `enter` and `backspace` keys on `input` events, and these key presses don't reach it

Comment: @Wouter -- Not that it's a big deal, but I think there's a typo in the code for jquery. I think you meant to add the parameter name "event" to the on-keydown event handler.

Comment: it doesnt seem to work with type = tel or type = password 
any ideas?

Comment: @ctb I think this would help: `<input placeholder="Please enter some data" type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myCall()" onpaste="anotherCall()">`

Answer (score 24):

## event.key === "Backspace"

More recent and much cleaner: use `event.key`. No more arbitrary number codes!

```
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    const key = event.key; // const {key} = event; ES6+
    if (key === "Backspace" || key === "Delete") {
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Comment: Sometimes event.key returns "Process" for a reason I cannot understand...

Comment: That is a supported browser. You may have a bug, or perhaps your custom keyboard doesn't fire keydown events

Answer (score 15):

With jQuery

The **event.which** property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode. It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input.

http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

```
jQuery('#input').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if( e.which == 8 || e.which == 46 ) return false;
});
```

Comment: I have been using jQuery a long time, but haven't seen this.  Always good to learn something new.  +1!

Answer (score 13):

It's an old question, but if you wanted to catch a backspace event on input, and not keydown, keypress, or keyup—as I've noticed any one of these break certain functions I've written and cause awkward delays with automated text formatting—you can catch a backspace using inputType:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    if (e.inputType == "deleteContentBackward") {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

## `keydown` with `event.key === "Backspace" or "Delete"`

More recent and much cleaner: use `event.key`. No more arbitrary number codes!

```
input.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    const key = event.key; // const {key} = event; ES6+
    if (key === "Backspace" || key === "Delete") {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Modern style:

```
input.addEventListener('keydown', ({key}) => {
    if (["Backspace", "Delete"].includes(key)) {
        return false
    }
})
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using 'onkeydown'?
This is the event you are looking for.

It operates before the input is inserted and allows you to cancel char input.

Comment: but how do I cancel it? because I'm using val() on the input and it still appends the typed character

Comment: How about `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: You can simply `return false;` to cancel any event when using jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

on android devices using chrome we can't detect a backspace.
You can use workaround for it:

```
var oldInput = '',
    newInput = '';

 $("#ID").keyup(function () {
  newInput = $('#ID').val();
   if(newInput.length < oldInput.length){
      //backspace pressed
   }
   oldInput = newInput;
 })
```

Comment: I really don't want this to be the answer, but it seems to be, since they set `which` and `keyCode` to 229. There must be a better way, or a better way coming soon, but I'll be using basically this for now...

Comment: Thanks , I was searching for android devices.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div[contenteditable]').keydown(function(e) {
// trap the return key being pressed
if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 8)
{
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: Key Code 8 for "BackSpace"

Comment: The question is about backspace and delete, not backspace and enter.

Comment: it will always return false, should be nested if

Answer (score 2):

`InputEvent.inputType` can be used for Backspace detection [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/inputType).
It works on Chrome desktop, Chrome Android and Safari iOS.

```
<input type="text" id="test" />

<script>  
  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  console.log(event.inputType);
  // Typing of any character event.inputType = 'insertText'
  // Backspace button event.inputType = 'deleteContentBackward'
  // Delete button event.inputType = 'deleteContentForward'
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Here's one example, not sure what your application is but here is a relevant and likely application 
function addDashesOnKeyUp()
{
    var tb = document.getElementById("tb1"); 
    var key = event.which || event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if((tb.value.length ==3 || tb.value.length ==7 )&& (key !=8) ) 
    {
        tb.value += "-"
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dexterity/cf6eub0o/45/)

```
Javascript
<br>
<input id="input">
<br>
or
<br>
jquery
<br>
<input id="inpu">

<script type="text/javascript">
var myinput = document.getElementById('input');
input.onkeydown = function() {
  if (event.keyCode == 8) {
    alert('you pressed backspace');
    //event.preventDefault(); remove // to prevent backspace
  }

  if (event.keyCode == 46) {
    alert('you pressed delete');
    //event.preventDefault(); remove // to prevent delete
  }
};

//jquery code

$('#inpu').on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (event.which == 8) {
    alert('you pressed backspace');
    //event.preventDefault(); remove // to prevent backspace
  }

  if (event.which == 46) {
    alert('you pressed delete');
    //event.preventDefault(); remove // to prevent delete
  }
});
</script>
```