# How to restrict user from deleting words with special characters from textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, restrict, ckeditor.net

I am working in email CMS using ckeditor.net. 
At runtime user can change the body of email, I want to  restrict user deleting all special words starting with @@ .

Here is example-

```
Email Alert! :<br />
<br />
**@@Comments**<br />
<br />
Please do not reply to this email.
```

I don't want user to delete "@@comments"  word and all  "@@" characters in other email templates .
Can you give any code in JavaScript?

At run time I replace "@@" words with some paragraph.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, try to use several text areas and readonly label (@@Comments) between them and use appropriate CSS classes, so it would look like 1 textbox.

Comment: well there must be some way to do that i mean when you can catch keydown and mouse click event then why not check there. Just need some more help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this code (just free-formed it into this response), but here's what I'd do.

On the keydown method of the text input, you need to [listen for the backspace key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906885/detect-backspace-and-del-on-input-event):

```
var input = document.getElementById('myInput');

input.onkeydown = function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    // Detect Backspace (8) & Delete (46) keys
    if( key == 8 || key == 46 ){

       var caretPos = getCaretPos(input);

       // Read backward from the caret position
       // until you hit a space or index 0:
       while ( (input.value[caretPos] != " ") && (caretPos > 0)  ){
          caretPos--;
       }

       // Once you hit the space or index 0, read forward two characters 
       // to see if it === "@@".  If both chars are "@", cancel 
       // the keydown event.  You should probably do some bounds checking
       // here.  Could also be done with String.subtring
       if ( input.value[(caretPos + 1)] == "@" && 
            input.value[(caretPos + 2)] == "@" )
       {
          return false;
       }
    }

};


function getCaretPos(input) {
    // Internet Explorer Caret Position (TextArea)
    if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        var bookmark = range.getBookmark();
        var caret_pos = bookmark.charCodeAt(2) - 2;
    } else {
        // Firefox Caret Position (TextArea)
        if (input.setSelectionRange)
            var caret_pos = input.selectionStart;
    }

    return caret_pos;
}
```

References

[Detect Backspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906885/detect-backspace-and-del-on-input-event)

[Get Caret Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928586/get-caret-position-in-html-input)

[Cancel the keydown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036243/cancel-the-keydown-in-html)