# Input Validation - How to allow backspace to work in my method

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a function that allow input field to receive numbers and the decimal point. How can I allow the backspace key as well ?

```
function verifierCaracteres(event) {

  var keyCode = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
  var touche = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);

  var champ = document.getElementById('mon_input');

  var caracteres = '.0123456789';

  if(caracteres.indexOf(touche) >= 0) {
    champ.value += touche;
  }

}
```

And my HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="Patient_Amount" id="mon_input" onkeypress="verifierCaracteres(event); return false;"/>
```

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906885/detect-backspace-and-del-on-input-event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `keyCode == 8` in your validation. 8 is the keycode for backspace.

Really, this is a job for regex and replace. That is how I typically go about this process. Here is an example.

```
function verifierCaracteres() {
    var inputEle = document.getElementById("mon_input");
    var value = inputEle.value;
    inputEle.value = value.replace(/([^0-9\.])+/g,'');
}
```

This will remove all characters from input that are not `0-9` or `.`