# Mozilla browser is treating backspace as special character

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keypress, mozilla

problem

- i was implementing user cannot enter special character in textbox.
- script is working on ie, safari, chrome but mozilla treating as special character.

what i need

- i need backspace  so that user can edit textbox values.

html code

```
    <input type="text" id="school" name="school"/>
```

js code

```
          $("#school").bind('keypress', function (event) {

        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        console.log(key);console.log(flag);
        if (!regex.test(key) && flag=="false") {
          console.log("if");

          //jQuery("#errmsg").html(localStorage.getItem("datas")).show();

          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
        }
        else
        {
          console.log("else");
        }
        //alert(data);



      });
```

- js fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/HGJb3/295/
- any help is most appericiated.

i came up with solution : http://jsfiddle.net/HGJb3/297/ now it works

Comment: Just catch it before regex test. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906885/detect-backspace-and-del-on-input-event

Comment: Additionally the reason it works in Chrome is because chrome does not fire the keypress event for a Delete key operation.

Comment: Note that even if you fix the backspace problem a keypress event handler alone can't stop the user from entering whatever values they like (because the keyboard isn't the only way to edit the field value).

Comment: i have solved the problem now it works