# How to reference "DELETE" and "BACKSPACE" correctly so i can use it on condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here im trying to prevent the deletion on input value when the length is only 2 or lower but if statement doesn't seems to right.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mobile').val("09"); // Set initial value to "09"
  
    $('#mobile').on("keypress", function(event) {
      let key = event.key;
  
      if ($(this).val().length <= 2) {
        if (event.key === "Backspace" || event.key === "Delete") {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
  
      if (!(/[0-9]/.test(key)) || $(this).val().length >= 11) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });
```

i've tried using keydown and keyup, both doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried `function(event)`?

Comment: function(event)? using vanillajs??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect backspace and del on "input" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906885/detect-backspace-and-del-on-input-event)

Comment: @WakilAhmed that does work, the problem is if i add the other condition it doesn't delete even when leght is 3 or higher

Comment: i was able to make it work by separating the two condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you should use keydown event.

Unlike the deprecated keypress event, the keydown event is fired for all keys, regardless of whether they produce a character value.

keypress only fired for keys which produce a character value.

just remove keypress and use keydown your code will work.

but as your telling it won't work you can use the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mobile').val("09"); // Set initial value to "09"
  
    $('#mobile').on("keydown", function(event) {
      let key = event.key;
  
      if ($(this).val().length <= 2) {
        if (event.which == 8 || event.which == 46) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
  
      if (!(/[0-9]/.test(key)) || $(this).val().length >= 11) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  });
```